# Yocto do_package() syntax to add recipe with scons.py

Tags: linux, scons, bitbake

I am trying to include the libjsoncpp package into my Yocto build, which is not currently included in Yocto's package list.  I downloaded the source files from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/files/jsoncpp/.  The package does not come with an INSTALL script but instead uses scons.py.  How can I write the install script for this as a recipe?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I am trying to do the same, and would *really* like to find a finished Bitbake file!

Comment: No, I'm afraid I didn't.  I was having a lot of difficulty using scons so I took a different route and removed jsoncpp from my project entirely.  Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Finally got this working perfectly but it involved actually patching their crummy SConstruct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the jsoncpp-src-0.6.0-rc2.tar from that link and didnt see any scons.py, even though the README says it should be there. I did however look through the SConstruct included therein, which is the main SCons build script.

To be able to use it, you will need to (obviously :) ) install Python and SCons, as indicated in the README: 
(I would recommend the latest version of SCons, which is 2.3.0, hopefully its compatible)

> - Building/Testing:   =================
>
> JsonCpp uses Scons (http://www.scons.org) as a build system. Scons
>   requires python to be installed (http://www.python.org).
>
> You download scons-local distribution from the following url:
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/scons/files/scons-local/1.2.0/
>
> Unzip it in the directory where you found this README file. scons.py
>   Should be  at the same level as README.
>
> python scons.py platform=PLTFRM [TARGET]

You should then be able to invoke scons from your scripts as follows:

```
$ scons -f <path to json>/SConstruct platform=linux-gcc
```

Substitute `linux-gcc` with your platform. Read through the SConstruct and search for `platform` to see all the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am still a little confused.  I have python scons.py platform=linux-gcc.  But then if I set "path to json" as the local directory extracted from jsoncpp-src-0.6.0-rc2.tar, I get the message "You must specify a platform".  Is this not the path I should be using?

Comment: I've got one final question if you don't mind.  My goal is to include libjsoncpp into the Yocto project, so that I can cross-compile everything onto an ARM processor.  Should I change the platform from linux-gcc to the ARM toolchain and add that toolchain to SConstruct?

Comment: @joshua.kurland, yes that would be the way to do it. I dont know about the ARM toolchain support in Scons, though. You may have to do some of that yourself, by setting the compiler and linker construction variables. Assuming its similar to linux, you'll need to set the CC, CXX, and other related variables on the env. Ask another question if you need more details.